# How to install XAP files in a windows phone 8.1 device

Tags: apps

I tapped *download and install manually* option in Windows Phone store and I downloaded an xap file. I transferred the xap file to my Lumia 435 via bluetooth, but the OS does not install it, displaying "Cannot install company app..." I checked out [This Microsoft Thread](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card) on how to install xap files. It says, "Tap more option on *apps list* and then tap install local apps (or SD card)." I don't see any such option in my apps list.

Answer (score 1):

The XAP file is signed using a certificate - most likely from Symantec. That certificate has a corresponding AET - Application Enrollment Token. You need to distribute the AET together with the XAP file in order to allow installation (Microsoft calls it a sideloading process).

Assuming this is XAP that you got internally, just ask the developer for the AET. if it is XAP that you created as a developer, find out how to generate it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735576%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)